# Find count from specific table by specific filter sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am Having table like this:

```
id  candid  candname        status      date       time     location    jobcode
1   12      hhhhhhhhhh      Introduce   2014-05-21 14:0     NewYork     10JN 
3   12      hhhhhhhhhh      Reject      2014-05-21 15:0 AM  London      10JN
4   12      hhhhhhhhhh      Interview   2014-05-21 15:0 PM  Chicago     10JN
5   11      Pinky Bare      Introduce   2014-05-21 65:6     India       10JN 
6   11      Pinky Bare      Interview   2014-05-21  4:56 AM             10JN
7   13      chetan Tae      Introduce   2014-05-21  4:54 AM Nagpur      faOl
8   13      chetan Tae      Interview   2014-05-21  3:45    Pune        faOl
9   14      manisha mane    Introduce   2014-05-21  3:33 PM Pune        faOl
10  18      ranju gondane   Introduce   2014-05-28  3:44    Nagpur      AQW-06
12  18      ranju gondane   Interview   2014-05-28  5:45    45454       AQW-06
13  18      ranju gondane   Reject      2014-05-28 43:43    rsds        AQW-06
14  19      vandanna rai    Introduce   2014-05-28  7:7     yyyr        AQW-06
```

if i use query

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [tablename] 
WHERE 
  (jobcode='AQW-06') 
AND
  ([status] <> 'Interview' AND [status] <> 'Reject' 
AND
  [status] <> 'ON-Hold' AND [status] <> 'Hire')
```

I get count 2 for introduce candidates..

if the candidate is interviewd after introduce, it will not counted as Introduce

I want the count of Introduce, interviewd, rejected candidates of specofic jobcode

Please help me for this.

Comment: If the candidate is introduce and inerviewd for the specific jobcode, then that candidated not counted in Introduced..  I have stages 1)Introduce 2)Interviewd 3)Reject 4)Hire

Comment: What about rejected candidate? Also, which DBMS are you using?

Comment: if th candidate is rejected then it will be counted as rejeted candidates not in Introduce and interviewd.. I am using SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
select status, count(*)
from [tablename]
where jobcode = 'AQW-06'
group by status
```

Edit: You can try use something like this

```
select count(x.candid) numofcandidates, x.statusnum
from
(select candid, max(case when status = 'Reject' then 3 
                         when status = 'Interview' then 2
                         when status = 'Introduce' then 1 end) statusnum
from [tablename] t 
where jobcode = 'AQW-06' 
group by candid) x
group by x.statusnum;
```

What I actually did is to "translate" the status to a number, so I can use the highest status first. All you need to do then it to "translate" back the statusnum to the values of your table. In my opinion I would use a statusnum in my table directly

Comment: In this query I am geting Result like this <pre>                       status       count
Interview 2
Introduce 3
Reject         1  </pre>                                                               But Once the candidate Interviewd, it will not counted as Introduced..  So the result will be  for the job code 'AQW-06'  like this    <pre>                                         status       count
Interview 1
Introduce 1
Reject         1        </pre>                                             But i am not getting right query for this...

Comment: In you question you state: "I want the count of Introduce, interviewd, rejected candidates of specofic jobcode". This sql will you exactly this if you specify the jobcode. For example for jobcode "AQW-06" you should have 2 with status "Introduce", 1 with status "Interview" and 1 with status "Rejected". If you want a candidate to be calculated only in one status (probably the latest) then this is a completely different question.

Comment: Please specify your RDBMS

Comment: in above table i have only 4 records for the jobcode 'AQW-06'           In that Introduce count is only 2 having candid 19 and 18 But once the candidate is interviewd the the candidate in not counted in Introduce. That is I have only one count for Introduce candidate having candid=19. I have step wise procedure candidated could not be Intervied directly.. Firstly candidate Introduce then Interviewd Then Reject then Hired

Comment: as per above table result for jobcode='AQW-06' is                        Status    count                                                            introduce  1                                                           interviewd 0                                                      Reject     1                                                          But I am not gettin How to write Query for this...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
;with reftable as
(select 1 'key', 'Introduce' 'val'
 union 
 select 2 'key', 'Interview' 'val'
 union
 select 3 'key', 'Rejected' 'val'
 ),
cte as
(select e.candid, e.[status], row_number() over (partition by e.candid order by r.[key] desc) rn 
 from yourtable e
 inner join reftable r on e.[status] = r.val
 where e.[status] in ('Introduce','Interview','Rejected')
 and e,jobcode = 'AQW-06')

select [status], count([status])
from cte
where rn = 1
group by [status]
```

Basically, we assign a numeric value to your text status to allow sorting. In the `over` clause, we sort by this numeric value in descending order to get the highest status of a candidate as you describe. Then, we just count the number of occurrences of each status.

Note that you can extend this to include values for status like 'Hire'. To do this, you will need to add it to the list in `reftable` with appropriate numeric value, and also add it to the filter in `cte`.

Answer (score 0):

> I want the count of Introduce, interviewed, rejected candidates of specific jobcode

The query below will return the results you need:

```
 SELECT SUM(t.IsIntroduction) AS CountOfIntroductions,
        SUM(t.IsInterview) AS CountOfInterviews,
        SUM(t.IsRejected) AS CountOfRejections
   FROM (
         SELECT id,
                CASE WHEN Status = 'Introduce' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS IsIntroduction,
                CASE WHEN Status = 'Interview' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS IsInterview,
                CASE WHEN Status = 'Reject' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS IsRejected
           FROM [Tablename]
          WHERE JobCode = 'AQW-06'
        ) AS t
```

Sample at this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4b188/6/0).